# Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

Getting exception in my java code

Exception:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess:C:\Users\mindurka\Desktop\SeleniumWorkspace\TestCaseSheet\TestCaseSheet.mdb;

```
         Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
         System.setProperty("DUCANACCESS_HOME","C:/Users/mindurka/Downloads/Selenium3.4/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin");

         String connURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess:"+TestCaseSheetPath+";";
         Connection objAccessCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
```

Have included all the five jars in the source folder in my library set

C:\UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin\UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin

I do not understand the reason behind this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jdbc:ucanaccess:C:\Users\mindurka\Desktop\SeleniumWorkspace\TestCaseSheet\TestCaseSheet.mdb
```

is not a valid connection URL. It needs to begin with

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://
```

followed by the path to the database file.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad.. I missed a double forward slash in the connection string. It should be ...

```
  Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
  System.setProperty("DUCANACCESS_HOME","C:/Users/mindurka/Downloads
  /Selenium3.4/ UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin");

  String connURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess:**//**"+TestCaseSheetPath;
  Connection objAccessCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
 Connection objAccessConData = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL1);
 Statement objRS = objAccessCon.createStatement();
```